# Multiply a specific column with multiple columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am new to R. My data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 1, 3), b = c(5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 1, 0, 2), x = c(4, 3, 8, 9, 1, 8, 2, 3))
> df
  a b x
1 1 5 4
2 1 4 3
3 2 3 8
4 3 8 9
5 8 6 1
6 9 1 8
7 1 0 2
8 3 2 3
```

I need to write a function to multiply the column `x` with other columns (here it's just `a`, `b` but I have 30-40).

Currently I have written a for loop which does the multiplication on column at a time. I need help to vectorize this and do the computation simultaneously.

Comment: Do you want to multiply all columns with entries in `x` (i.e. `a*x`, `b*x`, ...), or do you want to multiply all columns (i.e. `a*b*...*x`)?

Comment: Very simple. `df$mult <- df$a * df$b * df$x` will do job for you.

Comment: If you have just numbers, you should consider a matrix rather than a data.frame

Comment: @MauritsEvers I want to multiply x with other columns - a*x | b*x |...

Comment: @RolandASc Yes, all the columns have only numbers. How do I proceed with a matrix?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the help of `mutate` from `dplyr` package:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(mul = a * b * x)

df
  a b x mul
1 1 5 4  20
2 1 4 3  12
3 2 3 8  48
4 3 8 9 216
5 8 6 1  48
6 9 1 8  72
7 1 0 2   0
8 3 2 3  18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply extract the column and multiply by the matrix. I this case "x" is the column that you want to use.

```
multiply <- function(df, x) { 
  ## extract the objetive column
  df1 = df[, -x]
  col = df[, x]
  df1 * col
}
```

which results in:

```
multiply(df, 3)
   a  b
1  4 20
2  3 12
3 16 24
4 27 72
5  8  6
6 72  8
7  2  0
8  9  6
```

Answer (score -1):

OR apply

```
sapply( df , FUN= function(xxx ){
 df$x * xxx }
 )
```